# Survival analysis sample size considerations

Tags: survival, sample-size, cox-model

In statistical modelling, it is advised to have at least 10 observations per predictor as a rule of thumb. It is further suggested that in survival analysis this corresponds to number of uncensored observations. Does censoring within this context include censoring at the end of follow-up?
How would this differ between Cox PH model and fully parametric setting? In parametric models even censored observations do contribute to likelihood estimation, so one would expect that a lot of censored (especially censored at the end of the follow-up) could compensate for lower absolute number of events.

Comment: From an intuitive angle, consider studying some medical intervention in a condition with a typical event time of 1 year. If your study only follows patients for 1 week, you'll have lots of censored data and very few events, and almost no power to detect any effects. You can't do much to fix the problem by studying many more people for 1 week and getting even more censored data - what you really need is a longer follow-up period so you can actually see some events.

Comment: But if you are interested in estimating 1-week survival, then having ton of survivors could increase confidence in estimating that 1-week mortality is very low. There are conditions where mortality for some groups of patients is very low even after for exmple 5 years, so absolute number of events will be low but many late censorsed patients could increase confidence in survival estimation at this timepoint.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/cox#sec-cox-samsize) is a good starting point.  What matters to the Cox model is strictly the number of events.  As described elsewhere in RMS what matters for estimating survival curves is the total number of events and total number of non-events for subjects following a “long” time.  Note that the 10:1 rule is a very, very rough approximation.  See papers by Richard Riley and myself for more refined sample size calculations aimed at achieving overall predictive accuracy.  You may need 200 observations just to estimate the underlying survival curve, with no covariates.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and reference. So, in the Cox model ,number of late censored patients does not matter (if what matters is strictly number of events)?

Comment: For estimating relative effects (regression coefficients) only the number of events matters.  For estimating S(t|X) everything matters.

Answer (score -1):

I think what the people you spoke with meant that if you have only 10 observations, and you "lose" some before the end of your time course, you lose detection power later on.